# XBRL Formula Feature in Altova Xmlspy

Tags: formulas, xmlspy, altova, xbrl

Does anyone know if the [XBRL Formula](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/formula/REC-2009-06-22/formula-REC-2009-06-22.html) Feature is or will be supported in the Altova Products (Missionkit, Xmlspy, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Altova Xmlspy version 2015 provides formula development feature.
You can develop a formula by using table linkbase

Answer (score 0):

XBRL formulas are not currently supported; not sure what Altova intends to do in future versions.